# Stack (array index out of bounds)

Tags: java, arrays, stack, indexoutofboundsexception

So I've made this stack program where I have created several methods, including `pop`, `push`, `isEmpty`. The size of stack is 10. So when I push more than 10 elements, it displays error

> Stack is full

which it should do. However, it gives an

> Array Index Out of Bounds

error when i'm trying to use `POP` method for more than 10 times. How do I prevent it from giving an error.

Here's the whole code

```
class Stack {

    final int MAX_SIZE = 10;
    int top;
    //int myVal = top;
    int[] stack;

    public Stack()
    {
        top=-1;
        stack = new int[MAX_SIZE];
        //stack[0] = top;
    }

    public void push(int item)
    {
        if (top == MAX_SIZE-1){ //stackIsFull
            System.out.println("Stack is full");
            return;
        }
        else{
            this.top++;
            //System.out.println(this.top);
            stack[this.top] = item;
            System.out.println(item + "at index" + this.top);
        }

    }

    public int pop()
    {
        if(top!= MAX_SIZE-1){//(top==-1){
        System.out.println("Stack is empty");
        return -1;
        }
        return stack[top];

    }

    public void peek()
    {
        System.out.println(stack[top] + "at index" + top);
    }

    public boolean isEmpty()
    {

        //return top == -1;

        if (top != MAX_SIZE-1){//(top == -1){
            return true;
        }
        return false;


    }

    public void search(int item)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<stack.length; i++)
        {
            if (stack[i] == item){
                System.out.println(item + " at index " + i);
                return;

            }


        }
        System.out.println("error");

    }
```

Comment: You should probably edit your question to tag it with the language you're using. I think it's C but can't be sure.

Comment: C does not have `System.out.println ()` function. The code is written in Java.

Comment: Put `top--;` at first line of `pop()`

Comment: putting top--; at the first line is crashing my entire program

Comment: In `pop()` and `isEmpty()` what is the meaning of `if(top! = MAX_SIZE - 1)`???  It will always be true unless stack has exactly 10 elements

Comment: @DigvijaysinhGohil , You are right; hence, i changed (top!=MAX_SIZE) to (top==-1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your `pop` methods removes elemenths 10th time, `top` will be equal to 0. At the 11th time to call `pop`, `if` condition will not be `true` and `top` will be decreased to -1. You try to `return stack [-1]`. An array can not have a negative index. So you get an array index out of bonds error.

**Try something like this**

```
public int pop()
{
  if (top==0){
    System.out.println("Stack is empty");
 return -1;
}
 int temp = stack [top];
 top--;
 return temp;
}
```

Keep in mind that if you push -1 to stack, your code will assume stack is empty while popping that element

Comment: could you help me fix that? so that when i call pop more than 10 times, it just prints out an error saying that the stack cannot be printed etc..

Comment: If you can post all of your code, it will be easier.

Comment: Did you changed pop method? This pop method is completely wrong.

Answer (score 0):

fixed the pop method

```
public int pop()
{
    if(top==-1){//(top==-1){
    System.out.println("Stack is empty");
    return -1;
    }
    top = top - 1;
    if (top<0){
        return top;
    }
    return stack[top];




}
```